# Azure web app with Identity Server 4 - Log Out Doesn't Work

Tags: azure, model-view-controller, logout, identityserver4

I'm using Identity Server 4 for my web app (AspNet Core) that's in Azure. When trying to log out the user, the app logs in automatically again.

When debugging locally, the log out works fine, but after deploying to Azure, it doesn't work. Here're different parts of my code:

I use AzureAD and AspNetIdentity for logging in.

Log out controller (executed when log out button clicked, /api/Logout/):

```
public async Task Logout()
    {
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("cookieschemaname");
        await HttpContext.Authentication.SignOutAsync("oidc");
    }
```

Azure AD configuration:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = schemeName,
            DisplayName = "AzureAD",
            SignInScheme = cookieScheme,
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = $"https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantId}",
            ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.IdToken,
            StateDataFormat = dataFormat
        });
```

CookieScheme Configuration:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "oidc",
            SignInScheme = "cookieschemaname",                

            Authority = Configuration.GetValue<string>("authority"),
            RequireHttpsMetadata = false,

            ClientId = "hybrid-mvc",
            ClientSecret = Configuration.GetValue<string>("secret"),
            ResponseType = "code id_token",                 
            Scope = { "proxy", "offline_access" }, 

            GetClaimsFromUserInfoEndpoint = true, 
            SaveTokens = true,
        });
```

The client initialization:

```
new Client
            {
                ClientId = "hybrid-mvc",
                ClientName = "Hybrid MVC Client",
                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.HybridAndClientCredentials, 
                AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser = true, 

                RequireConsent = false,
                ClientSecrets =
                {
                    new Secret(secret.Sha256())
                },

                RedirectUris           = { uri + "/signin-oidc" },
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { uri + "/signout-callback-oidc" },
                LogoutUri = uri + "/api/Logout",
                AllowedCorsOrigins =     { uri },

                AllowedScopes = {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,
                    "queryproxy"
                },
                AllowOfflineAccess = true,
                UpdateAccessTokenClaimsOnRefresh = true
            },
```

**UPDATE**

I managed to resolve the issue by deleting the cookies manually in the identity server's logout method. I already had this implemented, but it had to be the first thing done in the logout method to work.

```
   foreach(var cookie in Request.Cookies)
        {
            Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie.Key);
        }
```

Comment: Can you describe the behaviour of it not working ? What actually happens ?

Comment: The PostLogoutRedirectUri is accessed (status code 302) and the app redirects to login page. There it automatically redirects to the redirect-uri and logs in the app.